# How to filter by tags in array when using JSON in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to store millions of time-series, where each point in time of every time-series is labeled with arbitrary set of tags. 
It appears I should use JSON array with tags in Snowflake:

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (obj_id INT, ts DATE, tags VARIANT, val INT)
INSERT INTO timeseries (obj_id, ts, tags, val) VALUES (442243, '2017-01-01', parse_json('["red", "small", "cheap"]'), 1)
INSERT INTO timeseries (obj_id, ts, tags, val) VALUES (673124, '2017-01-01', parse_json('["red", "small", "expensive"]'), 2)
INSERT INTO timeseries (obj_id, ts, tags, val) VALUES (773235, '2017-01-01', parse_json('["black", "small", "cheap"]'), 3)
```

Now I want to see an average of all time-series labeled with "small" AND "cheap", e.g.

```
SELECT ts, AVG(val)
FROM timeseries
WHERE "small" IN tags AND "cheap" IN tags
GROUP BY ts
```

which would return:

```
ts, avg(val)
2017-01-01, 2
```

What is the right Snowflake syntax/schema/approach to achieve it?
Note, I do NOT want to FLATTEN exploding the rows, I just want to filter out all the rows that are not 'cheap' and 'small'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using JSON, you can use array types directly E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ts2 (obj_id INT, ts DATE, tags ARRAY, val INT);
INSERT INTO ts2 (obj_id, ts, tags, val) select 442243, '2017-01-01', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('red', 'small', 'cheap'), 1;
INSERT INTO ts2 (obj_id, ts, tags, val) select 673124, '2017-02-01', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('red', 'small', 'expensive'), 2;
INSERT INTO ts2 (obj_id, ts, tags, val) select 773235, '2017-01-01', ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('black', 'small', 'cheap'), 3;
```

The VALUES clause cannot use functions such as ARRAY_CONSTRUCT, but INSERT-SELECT will work.  (You could also do this with JSON and a VARIANT type, but then you would need to tag the value with a key name, and use PARSE_JSON in the insert.)

Then to query rows that only contain exactly both tags you chose, use a query like this:

```
select 
  obj_id,
  tags
from ts2
where ARRAY_CONTAINS('small'::variant, tags)
  and ARRAY_CONTAINS('cheap'::variant, tags)
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out!

Comment: ARRAY_CONTAINS should work also on Andrey's way of loading data, btw.

Comment: Indeed!  That function just became available in Snowflake last week :)